# create VBA for copy and adding sheet 2 while copy paste row in first sheet1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

question.

I need a VBA Code to copy a complete worksheet when inserting a copied row in the first sheet. 
For example: 
Sheet one; row A1:N1 has formulas, they are combined with sheet 2.

Now copied row A1:N1 to A2:N2 this Module than needs to copy sheet 2 and insert it after it. whit all the formulas combined with row A2:N2 from sheet 1..

and so on..

is that even possible??

[WP sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ry8d.png)
[WPS samples 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXLST.png)

In "WP sample 1";

Row A14 "WPS 1" is linkt to "worksheet WPS1" (WPS sample 2)
Row A15 "WPS 2" is linkt to "worksheet WPS2"

-I want to create "WPS 3", so I am going to copy row A 14 and paste this info under A 15.

This VBA needs to copy "Worksheet "WPS1" and ad this copy after worksheet "WPS2"

So it creates WPS3, this need to have the same formulas in it as "WPS1"

thnx in advanced.

Mitch

Comment: Your question is very unlear to me. Can you provide sample data or pictures of before and after? Do you want to make a copy of a Worksheet object? Do you just want to alter the formulas?

Comment: Hello Branislav, I have added some pics and info, hope you can help me out with this one. if you still need more info. please ask.  grtz Mitch

Answer (score 0):

You can try similar procedure:

```
Public Sub copyWPS1asNew()
    Dim NameInput As String 
RequestName:
    NameInput = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Type new name of the WPS.", Title:="WPS Name", Default:="WPS2", Type:=2) 'type:=2 is String

    'check if the name is taken
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        If Ws.Name = NameInput Then
            MsgBox "That name is already taken. Try a different one.", vbExclamation, "Try different name"
            GoTo RequestName
        End If
    Next

    'create new sheet
    Dim NewWs As Worksheet
    Worksheets("WPS1").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set NewWs = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    NewWs.Name = NameInput
End Sub
```

Some custom tweeks are needed maybe. Hope this gets you started.
The check if the name is taken part can be made into custom function, to make the code more reusable.

Comment: The only thing that I miss now, is formula reverence. The worksheet that it copies,  does still have the formula reverence to row that I have copied from.  Is there any way to change all the formulas to the row that I have copied to??

Comment: @mitchel yes it is possible. Multiple solutions come to mind. You can create multiple hidden sheets and unhide them on demand. You can make worksheet change event to create sheets automatically based on last row. You can add multiple buttons, each creating sheet and formulas according to it's row. You can make UDF that searches WS name in the WP sheet and uses their name as indirect reference, ...

Comment: uhm, guess I do now nothing about excel... witch of the summed option is the easiest to handle?

Comment: @mitchel It heavilly depends on implementation. The easiest way I guess, would be to pre-create the sheets, not create them on user demand. You (as designer) can create all the sheets and make all the formulas, then send it to users. The file will be bigger (maybe unnecessary), but ready to use. Even without VBA, without advanced knowledge of Excel. You just have to decide, how many sheets may be needed, and add a few as reserve.